# Internationalization (i18n) with Spring MVC + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf

So I'm new with all the Spring Framework stuff and I'm working in a project that uses Spring MVC, BUT DOESN'T USE SPRING BOOT. The problem is, I need to implement the internationalization (i18n) with THYMELEAF AND SPRING MVC, WITHOUT BOOT, and all the examples that I have found use Spring Boot too. Is there some way to set up the example below without Spring Boot, only MVC and THYMELEAF? Thanks.

**aplication.java**

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApp implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return sessionLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor result = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        result.setParamName("lang");
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**controller.java**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/i18n")
    public ModelAndView i18n() {
        return new ModelAndView("i18n_page");
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-thymeleaf-i18n</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you aren't using Spring Boot then why the starters and the maven plugin?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The code above it's not mine or my project code. It's just an example that I found on GitHub, I was expecting to learn throught that code, removing the Spring Boot from there and setting up only the MVC + Thymeleaf. Just so I can have an example to follow on my own code.

Comment: Currently it looks like the code you are using, it isn't clear from your question. How to use I18N with Thymeleaf and Spring is actually al there (in the configuration above).

Comment: You may package the app as WAR and deploy it into a JEE Server then, spring-boot uses embedded server, so you need to re-shuffle dependencies, and remove spring-boot-*.  For the right project structure, better re-create the project with mvn or gradle.